# Is injecting repository in aggregate root / entity considered bad design?

Tags: domain-driven-design

I am trying to learn about details of domain driven design and i came to this question.
I found many examples with:

1. Defining repository interface within the domain
2. Defining repository implementation somewhere else
3. Inject repository interface into aggregate root

On the other hand, there are examples that strictly go against it and do all repository related stuff from service.

I cannot find authoritive answer and explanation: is it considered a bad practice and if so - why?

Comment: To be able to better answer your question I'd first take a step back, and think about: Why do you need the repository inside the aggregate?

Comment: Probably more suitable for [programmers.se].

Comment: @GoloRoden To have, for example, `Aggregate.Save()` method that would inside use `IRepository` interface to save. Alternative is, of course, to have a service that makes instance of aggregate, call whatever its business operations methods it needs and then call `IRepository.Save(Aggregate aggregateInstance)`. (If that answers your question)

Comment: What I would have responded now is similar to what @VoiceOfUnreason has already written in their answer. So I don't add another answer, but I'm going to +1 it :-)

Comment: Thanks for your comment! If there is anything you would add to @VoiceOfUnreasons answer, please put it in another answer and i will vote it up.

Comment: @JJJ when referring other sites, it is often helpful to point that [cross-posting is frowned upon](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I cannot find authoritive answer and explanation: is it considered a bad practice and if so - why?

Yes, mostly because a number of different concerns get confused.

Aggregates define a consistency boundary; any change of state should be restricted to a collection of related entities that are all part of the same aggregate.  So once you have looked up the first one (the "root" entity), you should be able to achieve the change without needing to examine any data other than this graph of domain entities and the arguments that you have been passed.

Put another way, `Repository` is a *plumbing* concern, not a *domain* concern.  Your domain entities are responsible for expressing your domain, without infrastructure concerns getting mixed in.

> To have, for example, Aggregate.Save() method that would inside use IRepository interface to save.

`Aggregate.Save()` definitely indicates a problem.  Well, two problems, to be precise: `Save` probably isn't part of your ubiquitous language, and for that matter its likely that `Aggregate` isn't either.

`Save` isn't a domain concern, it's a persistence concern - it just copies data from your in memory representation (volatile storage) to a durable representation (stable storage).  Your domain model shouldn't need to know anything about that.

One of the reasons you found "many examples with" is that getting these concerns separated correctly is *hard*; meaning you really need to think deeply about the problem to tease them apart.  Most examples don't, because teasing things apart isn't critical when you always deploy everything together.

Comment: "Save probably isn't part of your ubiquitous language" - thank you for this sentence! That makes complete sense and yes, i definitely overlooked that aspect od DDD. I was focusing on where the saving implementation is and the fact that its outside domain (and injected) seemed maybe acceptable. But having on mind the main purpose of domain, `save` definitely don't belong to ubiquitous language. This illustrates how important 'return to basics is'. Thank you very much for this answer!